# Spring WebFlux - Add a wrapping class before serialization

Tags: json, spring, kotlin, jackson, spring-webflux

I'm developing APIs for an exam project, but I wanted their responses to be consistently  using a wrapping class on all of them (Telegram Bot API style for those who know them).

So, for example, having these two classes:

```java
public class User {
    public int id;
    public String name;
}

public class Item {
    public int id;
    public String itemName;
    public User owner;
}
```

What Spring returns to me is this output:

```json
{
    "id": 1,
    "itemName": "theItem",
    "owner": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "theUser"
    }
}
```

---

What I want instead is for this output to be returned:

```json
{
    "ok": true,
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "itemName": "theItem",
        "owner": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "theUser"
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe using a class wrapper like this:

```java
public class ResponseWrapper<T> {
    public boolean ok;
    public T data;
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Yes it is possible. You approach is perfetto!

Comment: @JustinMathew thanks, but how? I want to apply that class globally, but I don't know where to put the "wrapping", I read about the "ObjectMapping" class, maybe extending that one?

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thank @JustinMathew for the help, at the end, in my case (using Spring WebFlux with Kotlin), the [ResponseBodyResultHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/result/method/annotation/ResponseBodyResultHandler.html) class was more useful to me.

```kotlin
// File: /MicroserviceApplication.kt

@SpringBootApplication
class MicroserviceApplication {
    @Autowired
    lateinit var serverCodecConfigurer: ServerCodecConfigurer

    @Autowired
    lateinit var requestedContentTypeResolver: RequestedContentTypeResolver

    @Bean
    fun responseWrapper(): ResponseWrapper = ResponseWrapper(
        serverCodecConfigurer.writers, requestedContentTypeResolver
    )
}
```

```kotlin
// File: /wrapper/model/Response.kt 

data class Response<T>(
    val ok: Boolean,
    val data: T?,
    val error: Error? = null
) {
    data class Error(
        val value: HttpStatus,
        val message: String?
    )
}
```

```kotlin
// File: /wrapper/ResponseWrapper.kt

class ResponseWrapper(writers: List<HttpMessageWriter<*>>, resolver: RequestedContentTypeResolver) :
    ResponseBodyResultHandler(writers, resolver) {

    override fun supports(result: HandlerResult): Boolean =
        (result.returnType.resolve() == Mono::class.java)
                || (result.returnType.resolve() == Flux::class.java)

    @Throws(ClassCastException::class)
    override fun handleResult(exchange: ServerWebExchange, result: HandlerResult): Mono<Void> {
        val body = when (val value = result.returnValue) {
            is Mono<*> -> value
            is Flux<*> -> value.collectList()
            else -> throw ClassCastException("The \"body\" should be Mono<*> or Flux<*>!")
        }
        .map { r -> Response(true, r, null) }
        .onErrorMap { e ->
                if (e !is Response.Error)
                    Response.Error(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, "Internal Server Error")
                else e
            }
        .onErrorResume { e -> Mono.just(Response(false, null, e as Response.Error)) }

        return writeBody(body, returnType, exchange)
    }

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        private fun methodForReturnType(): Mono<Response<Any>>? = null

        private val returnType: MethodParameter = MethodParameter(
            ResponseWrapper::class.java.getDeclaredMethod("methodForReturnType"), -1
        )
    }
```

---

**Edit**: I made of this answer a library for Spring WebFlux 2.7.3 [here](https://github.com/giuseppe998e/spring-webflux-response-wrapper).

---

**P.S.** I also took a cue from this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705172/webflux-doesnt-support-responsebodyadvice-yet), which faces the same problem but with Java.

Comment: Sorry I did't realized you are looking for webflux. I have edited my answer now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I understand you need a global setting to convert all your responses into a standard one. For this you can implement [ResponseBodyAdvice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/ResponseBodyAdvice.html) and have a common structure for all your api responses. Refer this [link](https://ashrithgn.medium.com/standardising-the-response-of-rest-api-in-spring-boot-spring-boots-responsebodyadvice-41e365ae89b) for a detailed example

Edit: For spring-webflux you can extend *`ResponseBodyResultHandler`* and override `handleResult`. An example is given in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53944781/8804776) answer